# Send Data via BLE in a Thread

Tags: android

currently, I am sending Data from my App to a Nordic Board with a thread. Sending again should only be possible when I have revieved an answer from my Nordic Board (notification). You can see that my code already works but the performance isn`t that good. I am using an AtomicBoolean to get sure if I already recieved a response from the board. In my Thread I wait until the AtomicBoolean gets true, if it is not true I let it sleep 200 millis. My issue is that sometimes not all packages get sent. Moreover I get stuck in the while-loop sometimes. Can you give me some advices to improve my sending performance?

Sending

```
 public void sendData(final String text) {
    refreshDeviceCache(bluetoothGatt);
    this.text = text;
    BluetoothGattService bluetoothGattService = bluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UUID_SERVICE_NORDIC));
    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristicRx = bluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UUID_SERVICE_NORDIC)).getCharacteristic(UUID_RX_CHARACTERISTIC);
    byte[] tx = new byte[0];
    tx = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    characteristicRx.setValue(tx);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int sendCounter = 0;
        int alert = 0;
        boolean isRunning = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                if (getSendingState.get()) {
                    bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicRx);
                    getSendingState.set(false);
                    alert=0;
                    if (sendCounter == 19) isRunning = false;
                    else sendCounter++;
                } else {
                    if (alert==2)
                    {
                        getSendingState.set(true);
                        alert=0;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert++;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(250);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.getStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    });
    t.start();


}
```

Revieving:

```
    if (UUID_TX_CHARACTERISTIC.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        Log.w("NOTIFICATION", Arrays.toString(characteristic.getValue()));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, Arrays.toString(characteristic.getValue()));
        byte[] bytes = characteristic.getValue();
        incomingDataAsString = new String(bytes);
        getSendingState.set(true);
    } // This is your code
```

DECLARATIONS OF THE CLASS

```
  private Binder binder = new LocalBinder();
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;
private String currentAddress;

//service state variables
private AtomicBoolean serviceBound = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private AtomicBoolean serviceStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);

//GATT states
public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";

//Service states
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
        UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);
public final static UUID UUID_RX_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UUID_RX_CHARACTERISTIC_NORDIC);
public final static UUID UUID_TX_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UUID_TX_CHARACTERISTIC_NORDIC);

//TAGS
private String BLUETOOTH_GATT_CALLBACK = "BLUETOOH_GATT_CALLBACK_SERVICE";
private String BLUETOOTH_CONNECTION_INFORMATION = "BLUETOOTH_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_SERVICE";
private String BLUETOOTH_ADAPTER = "BLUETOOTH_ADAPTER_SERVICE";
private String FUNCTIONAL_METHODES = "FUNCTIONAL_METHODES_SERVICE";


//Connection states
private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;
private int connectionState;
private boolean NOTIFICATION_ENABLED = false;

//VARIABLES FOR FUNCTIONAL USAGE
private String incomingDataAsString = "";
private AtomicBoolean getSendingState = new AtomicBoolean(true);
private AtomicInteger notificationCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

Kind Regards,
Thomas

Comment: getSendindState.set(true/false)...

Comment: I declared it at the top of my class. 

 private AtomicBoolean getSendingState = new AtomicBoolean(true);
the initial state is true, so I can start sending. After I have sent the my data it gets false. When the notification from the board arrives it gets true again. Sending is possible again...and so on

Comment: My Thread is declared like an inner class, so I can see even private variables.

Comment: I have added the declarations now. Not all of them are used yet. But they aren`t important for my question anyway

Comment: `I am using an AtomicBoolean to... `. Well name it!

Comment: I dont understand your approach. Where is it set to true? Who does that? You should only start a sending thread when you received a notification. All these sleep() calls are no good.

Comment: Also we have no idea what you do with `if (alert==2)`.

Comment: That is the point. I know that it is not good to let it sleep. But this was the only way to make it work. You are right I should have explain why I need alert. I am using it to avoid getting stuck in the while. I noticed that I sometimes get stuck in the else-case when isSendingState is false. This is just a really ugly way to avoid that

Comment: You must wait for the onCharacteristicWrite callback. That's when you can send the next data packet. But I don't understand your empty writes.